# Hom to align error message in dropzone

Tags: jquery, css, dropzone.js

I've got this text, when I upload file with wrong type

[image]

How can I align it under progress-bar?
This is the html code of element

```
<div class="table table-striped files" id="logopreviews">
            <div id="template" class="file-row">
                                    <div>
                    <span class="preview"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></span>
                </div>
                <div>

                    <p class="name" data-dz-name></p>
                    <strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></strong>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="size" data-dz-size></p>
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button data-dz-remove class="close" type="button">
```

This is my css. Div, which contains message lies there #AddLogoForm div.table .file-row > div

```
#AddLogoForm div.table .file-row {
    display: table-row;
}

    #AddLogoForm div.table .file-row > div {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: top;
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    #AddLogoForm div.table .file-row > div:first-child {
        border-left:1px solid #ddd;
    }
    #AddLogoForm div.table .file-row > div:last-child {
        border-right:1px solid #ddd;
    }
    #AddLogoForm div.table .file-row:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #f9f9f9;
    }
```

Comment: It's probably `div`'s width which is causing this but please post some code, so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Please post your css.